# How to set up JSON columns with Npgsql?

Tags: c#, json, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm setting up a mini model and I'm getting this exception when executing the code from the [docs website](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html#poco-mapping).

Here's my code:

```cs
  public class SomeEntity
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
  }

  public class Customer    // Mapped to a JSON column in the table
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Order[] Orders { get; set; }
  }

  public class Order       // Part of the JSON column
  {
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string ShippingAddress { get; set; }
  }
```

```cs
using (var dbContext = services.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>())
{
  await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();

  dbContext.SomeEntities.Add(
    new SomeEntity
    {
      Customer = new Customer
      {
        Name = "Roji",
        Age = 35,
        Orders = new[]
        {
          new Order { Price = 3, ShippingAddress = "Somewhere" },
          new Order { Price = 3, ShippingAddress = "Nowhere" }
        }
      }
    });

  await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

When I call `SaveChanges`, I get the following exception:

> Npgsql.PostgresException:
>   42P01: relation \"SomeEntities\" does not exist

[Here](https://github.com/weitzhandler/PostgrePlayground)'s a **repro** project.

Since I believe I followed all the steps in the manual, I've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2903) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the MigrateAsync method, but your project doesn't have any actual migrations (those can be created with `dotnet ef migrations add <name>`). If you're just playing around, you likely want to call dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated instead, [see this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created).

Comment: It did answer my question but the error still persisted when trying to access the DB afterwards. The answer for that error is that raw SQL query is different in PG and should be formatted differently. Thanks for your answer. I guess PG isn't 1:1 with SQL Server after all, but I'm still gonna stick to it because it's way more powerful to what I've found so far.

Comment: I can see it when using the Npgsql VSIX, if I query `SELECT * FROM SomeEntities`, I get that error ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Ub3Rejf.png)), but if I execute `SELECT * FROM public."SomeEntities"`, I get [this](https://i.imgur.com/6D4yPrp.png) error, but I do get the results thereafter ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/kjjbLsU.png)).

Comment: Be mindful that PostgreSQL folds unquoted identifiers to lowercase, so `SomeEntities` becomes `someentities` (and probably triggers an error). Quotes make sure that case is preserved.